# Recode multiple columns according to a key in R

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I'm trying to recode multiple columns according to a pre-generated key. I would normally just write a manual *recode* but it would save me a lot of time if I could just tell the code to reference the key.

My data looks like this:

```
  df <- data.frame(a = c('apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'peach', 'strawberry'), b = c('strawberry', 'peach', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple'))
df
#  a          b
#1 apple      strawberry
#2 banana     peach
#3 pear       pear
#4 peach      banana
#5 strawberry apple

  key <- data.frame(id = 1:5, label= c('apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'peach', 'strawberry')
key
#  id label
#1 1  apple
#2 2  banana
#3 3  pear
#4 4  peach
#5 5  strawberry
```

I would like to write some code to transform it by referencing the key:

```
#  a  b
#1 1  5
#2 2  4
#3 3  3
#4 4  2
#5 5  1
```

I've tinkered with some *ifelse* statements:

```
df[,1] <- ifelse(df$a %in% key$label, df$a == key$id, 999 )
```

This just gives me a column of true false statements though. I'm not sure whether *ifelse* statements can make precision cell by cell changes like that.

Anyway, I'm open to all ideas.

Comment: `df[] <- key$id[match(as.matrix(df), key$label)]`

Comment: assuming `df` is data and `match_pairs` is matching keys, do `df %>% left_join(match_pairs, by = c("id" = "a")) %>% left_join(df, by = c("b" = "id"), suffix = c("_old", "_New"))`